# How to fetch data from manytomany field django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

As i have many user. i want to fetch the name of users join a particular session in
`Players_Participating`

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):

    user_name=models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True,null=True,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user_name)
```

---

```
class Session(models.Model):

    Host=models.ForeignKey(MyUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='host')
    game=( 
        ('cricket','cricket'),
        ('football','football'),
        ('basketball','basketball'),
        ('hockey','hockey'),
        ('gym','gym'),
        ('baseball','baseball'),
    )

    Sport=models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=game)

    Players_Participating=models.ManyToManyField(MyUser,related_name='related')
    def __str__(self):

        return str(self.Host)
```

Comment: Have you tried any query? Please post whatever you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using prefetch_related like this:

```
s = Session.objects.get(that particular session).prefetch_related('host')
```

Also, this question has been answered previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60466424/displaying-the-value-of-manytomany-relationship-in-django-admin/60466515#60466515) AND [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43187327/django-get-data-from-foreign-key/43187687)
You'll find a lot of links there that will be helpful to you. :)

Comment: suppose i created a session of cricket ,i want to add myself or others too,i want to fetch those users,